# Swift dictionary to JSON+NSData extension

Tags: swift

I'm doing the same operation again and again, namely converting a dictionary to JSON and NSData.
Using Dan Kogai's JSON class https://github.com/dankogai/swift-json, I want to create an extension as follows:

```
extension Dictionary {
   func toDataJSON() -> NSData? {

       return JSON(self as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)
                   .toString(pretty: false)
                   .dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
   }
}
```

I realize that not all `Dictionary<key, value>` sets are compatible with JSON, but for the sensible combination like `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>`I would like the above to work.

The compiler says:

> 'Key' is not  identical to 'String'

Without casting `self` to `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>` it says:

> Type 'Dictionary' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'

Any insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Dictionary` is a template class, and since you can't extend specific variants of a template class (you want `extension Dictionary<String, AnyObject>`, you won't be able to do this like you want.  Your best bet is probably a global function:

```
func toDataJSON(dict:Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) -> NSData? {
    ...
}
```

Something else which might make things more legible is to create a typealias:

```
typealias JSONObject = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
```

Comment: Thank you, I feared as much.